# Is there a way to reopen microphone permission popup on chrome once a user clicks on custom button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say a user initially blocks mic/camera access.
https://prnt.sc/Spuu7smZH-tP

I have a custom button (allow access) and when a user clicks on it,it should reopen the browser popup.

I have been going through the pages but once a user denies then he is not able to see the browser popup again.

Code --

```
 const [isCamBlocked, setIsCamBlocked] = useState(true);
  const [isMicBlocked, setIsMicBlocked] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator?.mediaDevices
      ?.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
      })
      .then((stream) => {
        // CLEAR STREAM
        const mediaTrack = stream.getTracks();
        if (mediaTrack.length) {
          mediaTrack.forEach((track) => {
            track.stop();
          });
        }
        setIsMicBlocked(false);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log('constraint error', e && e.name);
        }
        setIsMicBlocked(true);
      });
  }, []);

  const openBrowserPopup = () => {
    navigator?.mediaDevices
      ?.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
      })
      .then((stream) => {
        // CLEAR STREAM
        const mediaTrack = stream.getTracks();
        if (mediaTrack.length) {
          mediaTrack.forEach((track) => {
            track.stop();
          });
        }
        setIsMicBlocked(false);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
       
        setIsMicBlocked(true);
        }

       
      });
  };

return (
    <AEButton className={'m-t-10 pointer'} block onClick={() => openBrowserPopup()}>
                Allow your browser access
              </AEButton>
)
```

Comment: It depends on the browser. In Firefox the user can decide to store the decision and the website can't ask again for permission: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-manage-your-camera-and-microphone-permissions#w_use-prompts-to-allow-or-block-camera-and-microphone-permissions-for-a-site

Comment: I want if a user clicks has already denied the request and clicks on a custom button ,then user should see the browser popup again.
Is there a way to achieve this or this is expected?

Comment: This is expected. If a user chooses to block the microphone and to store the decision, there shouldn't be another pop-up.